# Detecting circles using circular Hough Transform does not work correct

Tags: opencv, c++11, hough-transform

I would like to detect circular objects using OpenCV and circular Hough Transform (`HoughCircles`). In the image I have 3 circles, but Im only able to detect one (or two of them) when set up the threshold. I would like to have more robust code that can detect all 3 circle and after that I will filter the interested circle (basically using the radius). But first how can I detect all 3 circles together. Any help? Here is my code

```
    #include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
    #include <iostream>
    #include <string>
    #include <vector>

    using namespace cv;
    using namespace std;

    int thresh = 100;
    int max_thresh = 9000;
    Mat src;
    void thresh_callback(int, void* );

    int main()
    {

                 cv::Mat src = cv::imread("w1.png");
                 resize(src, src, Size(640,480), 0, 0, INTER_CUBIC);
                  char* source_window = "Source";
                  namedWindow( source_window, CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
                  imshow( source_window, src );

                  createTrackbar( " Canny thresh:", "Source", &thresh, max_thresh, thresh_callback );
                  thresh_callback( 0, 0 );

    waitKey(0);
    return(0);
    }

    void thresh_callback(int, void* ) {

          Mat src_gray, gray;
          cv::Mat bgr_image = cv::imread( "w1.png");
          cv::Mat orig_image = bgr_image.clone();

         //blur( bgr_image, src_gray, Size(1,1) );
           medianBlur(bgr_image, src_gray,1);
          //cv::GaussianBlur(bgr_image, src_gray, cv::Size(1, 1), 1, 1);
          cvtColor( src_gray,gray, CV_BGR2GRAY );

        Mat canny_output;
        Canny( gray, canny_output, thresh, thresh*1, 5,true );

                    Mat bw,dil,bw1,erd;
                    dilate(canny_output,dil,Mat());
                    erode(dil,erd,Mat());
                    Mat tmp=canny_output.clone();
                    Size kernalSize (15,15);
                    Mat element = getStructuringElement (MORPH_RECT, kernalSize, Point(9,9)  );
                    morphologyEx( canny_output, bw1, MORPH_CLOSE, element );

            // Use the Hough transform to detect circles in the combined threshold image

std::vector<cv::Vec3f> circles;
            cv::HoughCircles(canny_output, circles, CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1, canny_output.rows/1.1, 10, 100, 10, 0);
            //cv::HoughCircles(blue_hue_image, circles, CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1, blue_hue_image.rows/1, 10, 100, 10, 0);
            // Loop over all detected circles and outline them on the original image
            if(circles.size() == 0) std::exit(-1);
            for(size_t current_circle = 0; current_circle < circles.size(); ++current_circle) {
                Point center(cvRound(circles[current_circle][0]), cvRound(circles[current_circle][1]));
                int radius = cvRound(circles[current_circle][2]);
                cv::circle(orig_image, center, radius, cv::Scalar(0, 255, 0), 10);
            }
            // Show images

             resize(orig_image, orig_image, Size(640,480), 0, 0, INTER_CUBIC);
             char* source_window4 = "Detected window on the input image";
             namedWindow( source_window4, CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
             imshow( source_window4, orig_image );

    }
```

Here the input image

[image: Input image]

The result image
[image: result detecting one circle by 4600 threshold]

Comment: I don't know why you think there are three circles. I can see at least 8.

Comment: ok I wonna detect only the main ones. two where one world is written and one on the door window. Im not interesting in some small or irregular ones or semi ones. Is that ok now?

Comment: Well, the "oneworld" on the left is more of an egg, and the circle on the door has a circle within a circle. But that's why you have thresholds, to match imperfect circles.

Comment: circle detection doesnt work for ellipses or eggs, only for circles ;)

Comment: with threshold Im able to get the two one world circle or the window one. But never all three together. So my questions is why. any help on that?

Comment: @user3035413: Hough transform changes pixels location to circle equation. Since, eclipse do not fit well, you are not able to catch'em all!!! See this: http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/edges/plot_circular_elliptical_hough_transform.html

Comment: Try simpleblobdetector. They do a better job in detecting circle like shapes